# How to execute Javascript synchronously with httprequest

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, execution

I have a [probably stupid] question but I have searched and searched and still not found an answer.

I have created a function which houses my httprequest calls to my server, and I pass the webservice URL and parameters for the POST method into the function. My event handling function which calls that web ball has to do something with the response.

Unfortunately, the code after calling the web call function is executing before I have the value that needs, which causes huge errors. My code looks like this:

```
function process_stuff() {
    do_stuff;
    var d = webcall(link, params);
    if (d == "OK") {
        do_stuff2;
    }
}

function webcall(link, params) {
    //httprequest...;
    return responseText;

}
```

The check for d is failing as it is executing the if statement before d is populated, so d remains undefined or null.. Please help. How to I get the code to wait until d is populated with a value from the webcall?

EDIT:

Here's the code as per your comments:

```
function checker () {
var d; // declare d here so it is global among process_logic() and give_alert()    
    function process_logic(callback) {

    var params = "func=" + encodeURIComponent("webcalls");
    params += "&text=" + encodeURIComponent("yadda");

    var linker = "http://www.wigital.co.za/test/test.php"; 
    d = webcall(params, linker, callback);
    alert(d + ' on line 63');

}

function give_alert(d) {

    if (d == "OK") {
        alert("Success");
    } else {
        alert("not so sure... " + d);
    }

}

//process_logic(give_alert(d));
process_logic(give_alert());

}


function webcall(a, link) {
// a = paramaters string, link is the URL of the web service
//alert(callback);
var d;
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

/* What to do when server responds - define this before sending to server */
x.onreadystatechange = function () {
    /* Error check */
    if (x.readyState === 4 && x.status !== 200) {
        return("PROBLEM: " + x.response);
    }
    /* Process response */
    if (x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200) {
        //alert("I have a return value");
        return x.responseText; 
        //alert(x.responseText);
        //d = x.responseText;
    }
};


/* send to server */
x.open("POST", link, true);
x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
x.send(a);

/*
if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(d);
}*/

}
```

I want the variable d in function give_alert() to be populated. It is currently undefined as give_alert() is executing before before webcall() is finished and returned a value...

Comment: You'll probably need to show us your complete code rather than `//httprequest...;` if you want us to be able to look for the problem.

Comment: This is a common problem with a bunch of patterns to solve it. Without more code it will be hard to come up with a solution to your specific issue, but try researching JavaScript `Promises` as one possible solution.

Comment: the word procedural is not correct in this context, you are looking for a synchronous execution.
to see if you are facing a bug or a wrong implementation, you will have to show the code you use to perform the http request.
generally, you will have to use a callback, or optimally a promise.
reference for promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: **NEVER** use synchronous AJAX request, it blocks the UI thread for the time of the request, conducting to a laggy experience.

Comment: @omerkarj The word synchronous is probably not what you are looking for in this context, as it is impossible to achieve. You want *sequential*.

Comment: the best solution would probably be ˋd = await webcall(...);ˋ . Have a look at *async functions* and *Promises*

Comment: @Bergi i stand corrected :)

Comment: Hey guys, below is my exact code. This is code by which I'm trying to test the principal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend passing a callback function into the web request.

```
function process_stuff() {
    do_stuff;
    webcall(link, params, callback);
}

function callback(data){
    do_stuff2;
}

function webcall(link, params, callback) {
    //httprequest...;

    //on success
    callback(response)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla's documentation  is [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request). Although you can perform the request, like:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

Use `request.open(..., false)` to make sync request. As suggested by the comments, use the method promise (don't block script execution).