# Synchronous download text file JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a really light weight web page that downloads a file and then displays content based on the file. There is no displayed content without the file, and I have no plans to scale up this webpage. I do not want to use async methods unless I absolutely have to.

How do you download a file in such a way that JavaScript will pause until the file is downloaded.

Comment: Synchronous AJAX is deprecated. Get used to it.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid async code? [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) is the modern choice and returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you can use to tell when the download has finished. [MDN has examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#examples).

Comment: But if you really want to do it, use `XMLHttpRequest.open()` with the `async = false` argument.

Comment: "Unless I have to", it is incredibly, strongly, *fervently* suggested. Avoiding async is delaying the inevitable.

Comment: That being said, this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42251648/691711

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your entire script in an [async IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) and await the single network request:

```js
// immediately invoked async function expression:
(async () => {
  // all of your sync code before the fetch request to get the file

  const response = await fetch(url);
  // handle response, parse data, etc.

  // all of the rest of your sync code after the fetch request,
  // which won't execute until after the fetch promise is
  // resolved as the response (or rejected)
})();
```